# Visualize multiline ruby exceptions in kibana 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk

I have setup the latest version of Kibana4 ElasticSearch stack. The logs are being pooled from remote app sources which are running on Ruby.

I want to search for Multi Line exceptions created by ruby. Is there a way in kibana where we can search for error and print the nearby lines as well ?

Example in the kibana search bar we can type something like "Uncaught exception"+5 lines ? ( Something similar to grep -c20 )

Alternatively can i create a filter / json query with similar logic on the kibana interface itself ?

Comment: Seems this is yet not possible ([Ref 1](https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/kibana-101/) )

It is still a pending feature request :([Ref 2](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/275))

Comment: That's why you have `multiline` filter in `logstash`